# BitMovin - mpd file throwing 404 in player

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I'm trying to setup live streaming using AWS S3 and BitMovin. Things are pretty much working however, my player cannot find a mpd file. Where does this file come from? The `.m3u8` file is being generated and being placed in the S3 Bucket by BitMovin but where is the `.mpd` suppose to get created. Am I suppose to do anything to generate this file or does BitMovin created it?

I've been working off this tutorial:
https://bitmovin.com/tutorials/dash-hls-live-streaming/

**Solution**

I had a typo in the stream key.

Answer (score 2):

The MPD (.mpd) gets created as soon as there is a valid RTMP push input incoming to be encoded. The tutorial already provide [two examples to create an RTMP push input stream with ffmpeg and Open Broadcaster](https://bitmovin.com/tutorials/dash-hls-live-streaming/#RTMP_Input_Examples) [1].

If you are using the Open Broadcaster, please make sure that you have configured all mentioned settings within the tutorial and that there is an input source available (see picture below).
[image: Open Broadcaster Input Source]

Further, please make sure that your S3-bucket is setup with valid [CORS settings](https://bitmovin.com/tutorials/mpeg-dash-hls-adaptive-streaming-aws-s3-cloudfront/#Setup_CORS_and_crossdomainxml_on_S3)[2] to enable a HTML5 playback.

- [1]
  https://bitmovin.com/tutorials/dash-hls-live-streaming/#RTMP_Input_Examples
- [2]
  https://bitmovin.com/tutorials/mpeg-dash-hls-adaptive-streaming-aws-s3-cloudfront/#Setup_CORS_and_crossdomainxml_on_S3

Best,
Gernot